# Two Implementations of Geometry Reader, but one isn't working

Tags: ios, swift

Why does

```
    GeometryReader { geometry in body(for: geometry.size)
```

work. But this doesn't?

```
    GeometryReader(content: { (geometry: GeometryProxy) -> Content in body(for: geometry.size)})
```

I get this error: Cannot find type 'Content' in scope

It's strange because aren't these identical? The difference is we get rid of the types because of type inference and the content label because that's inferred too.

Moreover, why does geometry contain so much information like size, etc? I'm not too familiar with geometryproxy and so I'll need to do more reading on it but would appreciate a brief explanation if it's not a hassle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You get the error `Cannot find 'Content' in scope` because that would not be the correct way to draw that information out. Note that within Apple's Docs, `var content: (GeometryProxy) -> Content` -- content is of type `GeometryProxy` and in your case you have `content` returns a closure containing `GeometryProxy`. These are 2 different statements.
2. `GeometryProxy` contains all the information related to `GeometryProxy`, [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/geometryproxy) is Apple's document on that.

Comment: Isn't content a function that takes in a geometryproxy and returns Content: ```content: (GeometryProxy) -> Content```